# stsci_python and pyraf: "no module named" error

Tags: python

I am trying to install and run PyRAF and the stsci_python (http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyraf/stsci_python) distribution on my RHEL desktop.  I follow the installation instructions and the packages install without incident.  However, calling "import pyraf" at the python prompt returns the ImportError "No module named tools" (referring to the attempted call "from stsci.tools import capable"); calling "import stsci.tools" at the python prompt yields the same error.  yet the installed package (stsci.tools-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/) is manifestly inside a "site-packages" directory that is on my Python Path.

I've struggled with installs, paths, and re-installs for a month on this -- any insight would be extremely welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I had installed PyRAF and stsci_pythion via the Ureka package, which creates an alias "ur_setup" corresponding to " eval `/home/ianc/.ureka/ur_setup -csh !*` ".  When I call ur_setup in a terminal, I can then directly call pyraf, or start python and import stsci.tools, without problems.  So: merely adding a call to "ur_setup" in my .cshrc seems to fix the problem.